# How do I display the requested url via a handler for parked domains

Tags: php, http, request

I have a web directory to which several parked domain names are pointing. What I would like to do is know which domain name the visitor requested via browser address bar or link.

I will have a single handler `index.php` that will determine the requested domain name and display content accordingly.

Something like: `Hello, and welcome to example.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would access the superglobal [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php) and its key `HTTP_HOST`:

```
echo 'Hello, and welcome to ' , $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```